# convert hover mouse to click

Tags: jquery, click, slide

I need to convert this code below to click because when I walk or mouse it fires, it is a very good effect on the cell but does not work very well.

Must pass the slides with the click of the mouse.

http://fiddle.jshell.net/k83gd/

Can anyone help me? Thank you.

Comment: Please post the code in the question.

Comment: Wait, do you just want to replace hover with click? **What have you tried?**

Comment: Is this what you want: http://fiddle.jshell.net/k83gd/4/

Comment: @KentAnderson we all like to help but please don't encourage questions like this.

Comment: Thanks Kent Anderson!!!! Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

You might look into jQuery's 'on()' syntax.

Also - when changing to a 'click' listener, it was incompatible with your setTimeout() invocation.

Check out:
http://fiddle.jshell.net/k83gd/6/

Comment: Hello, if you found any of the answers useful, please select one as the official answer. Building reputations helps a lot on this site. Thank you!